# Regexp in oracle to match a string

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to create a RegExp in oracle to match a string with the following criteria,

Length 11 characters.
The 2,5,8,9 characters are letters [A-Z ] except ( S,L, O,I,B and Z).
The 1,4,7,10,11 characters are numeric [0-9].
3rd and 6th will b either a number or a letter.

Comment: Write a simple  `PL/SQL` function..

Comment: Do you want the string to be the matchable string, or even to contain the string?

Comment: (1) Does "letter" for positions 3 and 6 mean upper-case letter? (2) Is performance important? Do you need to do this for a lot of values, or for a moderate number of values many times (in a short time)? In that case, why do you insist on Regexp? A solution using only "standard" string functions may be MUCH faster.

Comment: The logic is to test one billion record, to find any or all the string not following this pattern.

Comment: @MubeenaElizabethMajeed, you might want to consider creating a function-based index using this regex pattern and either `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` or `REGEXP_INSTR()` (`REGEXP_LIKE()` can't be used in this way because it only returns a boolean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the following regex with `REGEXP_LIKE()`, `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`, etc:

```
^[0-9][AC-HJKMNP-RT-Y][A-Z0-9][0-9][AC-HJKMNP-RT-Y][A-Z0-9][0-9][AC-HJKMNP-RT-Y]{2}[0-9]{2}$
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Make a fancy Character List**

I just make a fancy character list excluding the alphabetical upper case letter you cited. This is similar to David Faber's answer.

Here is my fancy character list:

-'`[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y]`'  -Oracle's documentation states that the hyphen is special in that it forms a range when in this character list.

To make this pattern succinct, I noticed that for the most part, this string follows a pattern of digit, alphabet, alphabet pattern.  Consequently, I placed this in a subexpression grouping which occurs 2 times (quantifier follows).

```
       SCOTT@db>WITH smple AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          '123456789ab' tst
  4      FROM
  5          dual
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT
  8          '1CC4DD7EE01'
  9      FROM
 10          dual
 11      UNION ALL
 12      SELECT
 13          '1CB4DD7EE01'
 14      FROM
 15          dual
 16      UNION ALL    
 17      SELECT
 18          '1C44D67EE01'
 19      FROM
 20          dual    
 21  ) SELECT
 22      smple.tst,
 23      regexp_substr(smple.tst,'^(\d[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y](\d|[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y])){2}\d[AC-HJKMNPQRT-Y]{2}\d{2}$') matching
 24    FROM
 25      smple;
TST           MATCHING      
-------------------------
123456789ab                 
1CC4DD7EE01   1CC4DD7EE01   
1CB4DD7EE01                 
1C44D67EE01   1C44D67EE01
```